# AngularJS: How to check auth from API using Transition Hooks of UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I make the transition hook wait for the `checkAuth()` request from my API to fail before it would redirect the user to the login page without the transition hook successfully resolving?

This is the transition hook code I have:

*app.js*

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function ($state, $transitions, AuthService) {
    $transitions.onBefore({ to: 'auth.**' }, function() {
      AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(function (isAuthenticated) {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          $state.go('login');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

I'm using the `$state` service to redirect the user to the login page when the unauthenticated user tries to access an auth restricted view. But with this implementation, the transition `onBefore()` is already resolved, so the transition is succeeding before my `checkAuth()` method finishes. So it's still showing the view its going to for a *(split)* sec, before it transitions to the login view.

Here is the implementation of the auth service methods used in the code above:

*auth.service.js*

```
authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
  // Checks if there is an authenticated user in the app state.
  var authUser = AuthUserStore.get();
  if (authUser) {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
  // Do check auth API request when there's no auth user in the app state.
  return authService.checkAuth()
    .then(function () {
        return !!AuthUserStore.get();
      });
};

authService.checkAuth = function () {
  return $http.get(API.URL + 'check-auth')
    .then(function (res) {
        // Store the user session data from the API.
        AuthUserStore.set(res.data);
        return res;
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Jonathan Dsouza for providing the HookResult documentation from UI Router.

This issue is resolved by handling the Promise from the `isAuthenticated()` service method, and returning the necessary `HookResult` value to handle the transition as required:

*app.js*

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function ($transitions, AuthService) {
    $transitions.onBefore({to: 'auth.**'}, function (trans) {
      return AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(function (isAuthenticated) {
          if (!isAuthenticated) {
            return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
          }
          return true;
        });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the onBefore hook,

> The return value can be used to pause, cancel, or redirect the current
>   Transition.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onbefore

Perhaps you need to look into HookResult and use it to suit you're needs.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html#hookresult

Hope this helps

Cheers!